# Cookies only set with web security disabled? (Node.js/Express.js app)

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, session-cookies

I'm using node/express to make a pure backend api. My front-end (angular.js) is hosted on a separate server. I have a few lines of middleware for every request to allow CORS.

If I start chrome with -args --disable-web-security flags, everything works great!

However if I start it normally, cookies seem to not be getting set in the browser, and therefore sessions on the node side aren't kicking in. This is the same for safari/mobile safari/etc.

I've tried browser options such as "accept all cookies"/"never block cookies". I thought maybe browsers don't like localhost but this is the same behavior on localhost and on actual hosted domains.

The flow is:

1. I login and the session is set with an id, on success the frontend is directed to the next page. This works, and I console logged req.session.id and it's correct.
2. On the next page a request is sent, the node server is configured to use the id in the session for this request. With safari/mobile safari/chrome the req.session.id is suddenly empty. With chrome -security disabled, the req.session.id is still correct and behaves just like it should.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Express and Node, how to maintain a Session across subdomains/hostheaders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071969/using-express-and-node-how-to-maintain-a-session-across-subdomains-hostheaders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to this answer that covers cross-domain cookies and session: [Using Express and Node, how to maintain a Session across subdomains/hostheaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071969/using-express-and-node-how-to-maintain-a-session-across-subdomains-hostheaders/14627464#14627464)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. However I tried everything in your answer and it's still not working. Could it be because my servers are not on subdomains, but completely different domains? 
For example, myfrontend.com/home is sending a POST to mybackend.com/login. 

I think it has something to do with my cookies settings
 `cookie: {
  path: '/',
  domain: 'mybackend.com',
  maxAge: 1000*60
 }`

Comment: You have to verify if cookie is sent on every request. Please let me know if it is sent or not. You can verify it by consoling cookies data at back end, and viewing Network tab headers for requests.

Comment: The backend is always sending a cookie (backend.sid = qjiwfb...).

With regular mode chrome, the client never sends any cookies for any requests. If I go to chrome settings -> manage cookies, the cookie is never set.

With -web-security disabled chrome, the client sends the cookie (backend.sid) and the app works perfectly. And if I go to chrome settings -> manage cookies , the cookie is there.

Comment: Please read in link above text related to special flag in XHR `withCredentials`, that might solve your problem.

Comment: It finally worked! I did have the `withCredentials` flag before, but I think I was accidentally over-writing in another place. Thanks so much!