# cookie not set on cross domain - angularjs and nodejs/express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, cross-domain

cookie is not set on cross domain request. my server is running in localhost:8000 and client side running in localhost:9000. cors settings on the server nodejs/express is

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.method);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Authorisation");
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.send(200);
} else {
    return next();
}});
```

Angualarjs is used in client side and the cors configuration is

```
SelappsAdmin.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on express

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'yoursecret',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: 'yourdomain.com',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    }
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

on angular

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
```

I found from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071969/using-express-and-node-how-to-maintain-a-session-across-subdomains-hostheaders)

Answer (score 5):

on express

```
app.use(require('cors')({
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    callback(null, origin);
  },
  credentials: true
}));
```

on angular

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] ='XMLHttpRequest';
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```